# How to center footer links in magento?

Tags: html, css, magento

Dear Stackoverflow community,

I just can't figure out how to center the footer links on my magento website. The footer links are within a div and the correspondig CSS is, as I believe, as follows:

I have tried everything, from margin:auto to margin-right and margin-left auto.
Then I thought, maybe the right footer, there used to be a newsletter box there, is forcing to take up space, so I slashed it out, but still no effect. Anyone any idea what could be the solution? Thank you so much!

```
 .footer-container { width:100%; text-align: left;}
.footer { margin: 0 auto 0;width: 940px; padding: 0 20px 30px; background: #fff; }
.aditional-footer { margin:0 auto 0; padding: 30px 20px 35px; width: 940px; background: #FFF;}
.footer .links li { text-transform: none;}
.footer-container a { color:#666669; font-size: 9px; }
/*.footer-container .footer-right { width: 250px; }*/

.footer .f-left { width:520px; text-align: left;   margin: 0 auto;}
/*.footer .f-right { width:420px; text-align: right; }*/
```

This is the HTML

```
<html>
<div class="footer-container">
    <div class="aditional-footer">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('bottomContainer') ?>
        <div class="f-right">
            <div class="footer-right">
                <div class="right-conteiner">
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('newsletter') ?>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="right-conteiner">
                    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('footer_time')->toHtml(); ?>
                    <?php if(themeOptions('topbtn')): ?>                    
                        <div id="back-to-top"><a href="#top" id="top-link"><?php echo $this->__('Back to top') ?></a></div> 
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
                </div>                
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="f-left footer-left">
            <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('footer_shipping')->toHtml(); ?>
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </div>  
</div>  
    <div class="footer">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('bottomContainer') ?>
        <div class="f-left">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer_links') ?><br />
            <?php echo $this->getCopyright() ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('cms_footer_links') ?>
        </div>
        <div class="f-right">
            <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('verify')->toHtml(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

Comment: Is they are links with a href, they should be addressed in the css. Try .footer-container a {text-align:center}. Based on the fact that your html should look something like <div class="footer-container"><a href="links"></a></div> with a parent div of width:100%; which is already applied to the footer container. Try also this footer{ margin: 0 auto; dont place another 0 after that.

Comment: Both changes have no effect. Even if they were to, aligning the text would only align the text. Not the entire div. The text would then just be in the center of the div, which is still left.

Answer (score 0):

Change the following code

```html
.footer-container { width:100%; text-align: left;}
```

to

```html
.footer-container { width:100%; text-align: center;}
```

Let me know if you have any query

Comment: Unfortunately, this only centers the text within the div, not the div itself :( Thanks for your input